# My script it works fine locally but when i run a build it "crashes"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

last year i make a webpage with create react app and javascript all worked fine and local tests too but when i run a build to deploy it i have tested with serve -s build or in firebase and when i want to see the information cards of the page show me this error[I try with many alternatives the array keeps with null information i receive the data from a sql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtOva.png)

the data is imported with axios and useeffect in other file where is imported to this script

```
import { useFunding } from '../../context/fundingContext'
import moment from 'moment'
import { Card, ProgressBar, CardGroup, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export function FundCards() {
    const { postsFunding } = useFunding();

    return ( 
        <CardGroup>
            <Row xs={1} md={3} className="g-4 rounded">
                {postsFunding.length() != 0 && postsFunding.map((post) => (
                    <Col>
                        <Card key={post.IdFunding}>
                            <Link class="btn" to={"/funding/" + post.IdFunding}>
                                <Card.Header className='text-wrap'>
                                    {post.Title}
                                </Card.Header>
                                <Card.Img variant="top" src={post.FundingImage1} />
                                <Card.Body>
                                    {post.CurrentGoal >= post.Goal ?
                                        <ProgressBar className="m-2" now={(post.CurrentGoal / post.Goal) * 100} variant="success" label={post.CurrentGoal + "Bs."} /> : <ProgressBar className="m-2" now={(post.CurrentGoal / post.Goal) * 100} variant="dark" label={post.CurrentGoal + "Bs."} />}
                                    <Card.Text className="p-2">
                                        <div className="flex justify-center ">
                                            <p className="text-muted">Meta: {post.Goal}Bs.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="text-wrap justify-center">
                                            <p>{post.FastDescription}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <Card.Footer>
                                    <small className="text-muted">Campaña subida el: {moment(post.RegisterDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</small>
                                </Card.Footer>
                            </Link>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </CardGroup>
    );
}
```

i tryed resolve incorrect syntax with bard and shows me this but the error keeps there and same...

```
import { useFunding } from '../../context/fundingContext'
import moment from 'moment'
import { Card, ProgressBar, CardGroup, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export function FundCards() {
    const { postsFunding } = useFunding();

    if (postsFunding.length) {
      return ( 
        <CardGroup>
            <Row xs={1} md={3} className="g-4 rounded">
                {postsFunding.map((post) => (
                    <Col>
                        <Card key={post.IdFunding}>
                            <Link class="btn" to={"/funding/" + post.IdFunding}>
                                <Card.Header className='text-wrap'>
                                    {post.Title}
                                </Card.Header>
                                <Card.Img variant="top" src={post.FundingImage1} />
                                <Card.Body>
                                    {post.CurrentGoal >= post.Goal ?
                                        <ProgressBar className="m-2" now={(post.CurrentGoal / post.Goal) * 100} variant="success" label={post.CurrentGoal + "Bs."} /> : <ProgressBar className="m-2" now={(post.CurrentGoal / post.Goal) * 100} variant="dark" label={post.CurrentGoal + "Bs."} />}
                                    <Card.Text className="p-2">
                                        <div className="flex justify-center ">
                                            <p className="text-muted">Meta: {post.Goal}Bs.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="text-wrap justify-center">
                                            <p>{post.FastDescription}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <Card.Footer>
                                    <small className="text-muted">Campaña subida el: {moment(post.RegisterDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</small>
                                </Card.Footer>
                            </Link>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </CardGroup>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>No hay registros</div>
      );
    }
}
```

Its the only thing now it doesn't works i have many cards with the same function but works same, i have that error too with this script.

```
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useFunding } from '../../context/fundingContext'

export function SearchByCategory() {
    const { postsCat, getPostsFundByCat } = useFunding()

    return (
        <DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="Buscar por Categoría" size="md" className="d-grid gap-2 m-2" variant="dark">
            {postsCat && postsCat.map((postCat) => (
                <Link to="/catalogue/category" style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>
                    <Dropdown.Item key={postCat.IdCategory} as="button" onClick={() => getPostsFundByCat(postCat.IdCategory)}>
                        {postCat.CategoryName}
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </DropdownButton>
    );
}
```

both are in the same view.

It need shows like this: (this is how it works locally with npm start)

[This is the result that needs to be showed in the build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU1On.png)